# not able to call ng-click in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest, angularjs-ng-click

I am a newbie and learning AngularJS, and I am stuck at a point and not able to figure out what is wrong I am doing. So I have a spring RESTful service and it is working fine but I am not able to call it on `ng-click`. Here is my code snippet

index.jsp

```
    <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="Controller1">
  <p>Create a new user:</p>
  <p>
    Name: <input data-ng-model="name" />
  </p>
  <button data-ng-click="createPerson()" >add</button>

  <p data-ng-show="newUserId">
    User created with id: {{newUserId}}
  </p>
</div>
</body>
```

My app.js

```
    var demoApp=angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);
    demoApp.controller('Controller1', function ($scope,$http) {
    console.log("In controller");
    var urlBase="http://localhost:8080/SpringAngularMaven/";
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


    $http.createPerson = function createPerson() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/SpringAngularMaven/rest/emp/dummy').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.tasks = data;
            console.log(data);
            $scope.newUserId = data;

        });
    };
```

Output
So when the page is loaded only the `console.log("In controller");` is executed and when I click on the button nothing happens....

Comment: uhm... **$http**.createPerson?

Comment: @KevinB: yeah I got it where I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookes like you have a typo in your controller.  You need to bind the `createPerson` function to the `$scope`

```
   var demoApp=angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);
    demoApp.controller('Controller1', function ($scope,$http) {
    console.log("In controller");
    var urlBase="http://localhost:8080/SpringAngularMaven/";
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    //Changed from $http.createPerson to $scope.createPerson
    $scope.createPerson = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/SpringAngularMaven/rest/emp/dummy').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.tasks = data;
            console.log(data);
            $scope.newUserId = data;

        });
    };
```

Comment: thanx man u saved my day, I was trying to bind it with http rather than scope. :)